# How to properly cycle through nth-of-type?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I realize that there's a tonne of information about this online and on this forum. I've read through a bunch of it and tried several different approaches, but for some reason I can't wrap my head around why this isn't working for me.

I have a series of articles that get added to a page via a loop. I want the background colour for the `cycle-colour-bg` class to be the same for instances 1, 4, 7, etc., then change the background colour for instances 2, 5, 8, etc., and then have a third colour for instances 3, 6, 9, etc.

Here's my markup from inside the loop (for each instance):

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <article class="masonary flex-cell">
        <div class="featured-image-secondary inner-border-10">
            <img src="some-image-url">
        </div>

        <div class="post-body-secondary cycle-colour-bg">
            <p class="fw700 post-title-secondary void-colour">Some Title</p>
            <a href="Some-Link">Read More</a>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

Here's the last bit of CSS I tried:

```
.masonary:nth-of-type(3n+1) .cycle-colour-bg {
    background-color: #707272;
}

.masonary:nth-of-type(3n+2) .cycle-colour-bg {
    background-color: #57caee;
}

.masonary:nth-of-type(3n+3) .cycle-colour-bg {
    background-color: #106db6;
}
```

I've tried both `nth-of-type` and `nth-child`, I've tried adding the nth selector to the `cycle-colour-bg` class and to the div before it. I don't know why I can't wrap my head around this, but any help in pointing out the obvious for me would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to target the parent element `col-sm-4`, select the `nth-of-type` from the list and then descend inside to select `cycle-colour-bg`.

Your current code would have worked if all the `masonary` items were inside `col-sm-4`

```css
.col-sm-4:nth-of-type(3n+1) .cycle-colour-bg { /* Target 1, 4 and 7 */
  background-color: #707272;
}

.col-sm-4:nth-of-type(3n+2) .cycle-colour-bg { /* Target 2, 5 and 8 */
  background-color: #57caee;
}

.col-sm-4:nth-of-type(3n+3) .cycle-colour-bg { /* Target 3, 6 and 9 */
  background-color: #106db6;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <article class="masonary flex-cell">
    <div class="featured-image-secondary inner-border-10">
      <img src="some-image-url">
    </div>

    <div class="post-body-secondary cycle-colour-bg">
      <p class="fw700 post-title-secondary void-colour">Some Title</p>
      <a href="Some-Link">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <article class="masonary flex-cell">
    <div class="featured-image-secondary inner-border-10">
      <img src="some-image-url">
    </div>

    <div class="post-body-secondary cycle-colour-bg">
      <p class="fw700 post-title-secondary void-colour">Some Title</p>
      <a href="Some-Link">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <article class="masonary flex-cell">
    <div class="featured-image-secondary inner-border-10">
      <img src="some-image-url">
    </div>

    <div class="post-body-secondary cycle-colour-bg">
      <p class="fw700 post-title-secondary void-colour">Some Title</p>
      <a href="Some-Link">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <article class="masonary flex-cell">
    <div class="featured-image-secondary inner-border-10">
      <img src="some-image-url">
    </div>

    <div class="post-body-secondary cycle-colour-bg">
      <p class="fw700 post-title-secondary void-colour">Some Title</p>
      <a href="Some-Link">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <article class="masonary flex-cell">
    <div class="featured-image-secondary inner-border-10">
      <img src="some-image-url">
    </div>

    <div class="post-body-secondary cycle-colour-bg">
      <p class="fw700 post-title-secondary void-colour">Some Title</p>
      <a href="Some-Link">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <article class="masonary flex-cell">
    <div class="featured-image-secondary inner-border-10">
      <img src="some-image-url">
    </div>

    <div class="post-body-secondary cycle-colour-bg">
      <p class="fw700 post-title-secondary void-colour">Some Title</p>
      <a href="Some-Link">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <article class="masonary flex-cell">
    <div class="featured-image-secondary inner-border-10">
      <img src="some-image-url">
    </div>

    <div class="post-body-secondary cycle-colour-bg">
      <p class="fw700 post-title-secondary void-colour">Some Title</p>
      <a href="Some-Link">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <article class="masonary flex-cell">
    <div class="featured-image-secondary inner-border-10">
      <img src="some-image-url">
    </div>

    <div class="post-body-secondary cycle-colour-bg">
      <p class="fw700 post-title-secondary void-colour">Some Title</p>
      <a href="Some-Link">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <article class="masonary flex-cell">
    <div class="featured-image-secondary inner-border-10">
      <img src="some-image-url">
    </div>

    <div class="post-body-secondary cycle-colour-bg">
      <p class="fw700 post-title-secondary void-colour">Some Title</p>
      <a href="Some-Link">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Manoj, this worked! Quick question if you don't mind: .masonary is also a parent, so why didn't that work?

Comment: I have updated the answer. In your code `nth-of-type` does not traverse behind to look for `col-sm-4`. So every time when it calculates `nth-of-type` it starts afresh and is equal to `nth-of-type(1)`.

Comment: Understood, finally - thank you!!